# Simple CLI File Encryption

Tags: c, console, cryptography, basic-lang

This program is designed to work on the command line by piping stdin to stdout and encrypting or decrypting the input using a symmetric key.

Any suggestions for improvement would be greatly appreciated. Error checking tips would be especially helpful.

encrypt.c

```
#include "lib/encryption.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    int opt = -1;

    char *key = NULL;

    int (*fn)(FILE*, FILE*, char*) = encrypt;

    while((opt = getopt(argc, argv, "dk:")) != -1) {
        switch(opt) {
            case 'd': fn = decrypt; break;
            case 'k': key = optarg; break;
            default:
                fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s [-d -k <key>]\n", argv[0]);
                return -1;
        }
    }

    if(key == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Key required.  Use -k <key> to indicate key value.\n");
        return -1;
    }

    return fn(stdin, stdout, key);

}
```

lib/encryption.h

```
#include <string.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define FC_ENCRYPT 1
#define FC_DECRYPT 0

#define RB_LEFT 1
#define RB_RIGHT 0

int rotatebits(int inchar, int offset, int lorr) {
    int tmpchar;

    switch (lorr) {
        case RB_LEFT:
            tmpchar = ((inchar << offset) | (inchar >> (CHAR_BIT - offset)));
            break;
        case RB_RIGHT:
            tmpchar = ((inchar >> offset) | (inchar << (CHAR_BIT - offset)));
            break;
        default:
            tmpchar = inchar;
    }

    return tmpchar;
}

int flipcrypt(FILE *fpin, FILE *fpout, char *key, int eord) {

    int tmpchar;
    int keylen = strlen(key);
    int ik, broffset;

    ik = 0;

    tmpchar = fgetc(fpin);
    while (tmpchar != EOF) {
        
        // broffset determines bit rotation offset based on key value
        broffset = (key[ik] % CHAR_BIT);

        if(eord == FC_ENCRYPT) tmpchar = rotatebits(tmpchar, broffset, RB_RIGHT);

        tmpchar = (tmpchar ^ key[ik]);

        if(eord == FC_DECRYPT) tmpchar = rotatebits(tmpchar, broffset, RB_LEFT);

        ik++;
        if(ik == (keylen)) ik = 0;
        fputc(tmpchar, fpout);
        tmpchar = fgetc(fpin);
    }

    return 0;
}

int encrypt(FILE *fpin, FILE *fpout, char *key) {
    return flipcrypt(fpin, fpout, key, FC_ENCRYPT);
}

int decrypt(FILE *fpin, FILE *fpout, char *key) {
    return flipcrypt(fpin, fpout, key, FC_DECRYPT);
}
```